# Syntax in R to use variable in place of field name in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many fields. I want to get some summary of 10-12 of the fields using summarize function. the concerned fields are named in seq like V1-V10. I am trying to write a function that will take input as 1-10 and then give summary of V1-V10.

```
BMI <-  data.frame(
V1 = c("Male", "Male","Female"), 
V2 = c(42,38,26),
height = c(152, 171.5, 165), 
weight = c(81,93, 78)
)
g <-     function(x)c(Mean=mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),Median=median(x,na.rm=TRUE),Min=min(x,na.rm=TRUE),Max=max(x,na.rm=TRUE))
t <- summarize(BMI$V2,BMI$V1,g)
t    
tt <- summarize(BMI$get(paste0("V",2)),BMI$get(paste0("V",1)),g)
tt
```

t is working fine. I expect t and tt to be same. But getting error for tt as below,

Error in summarize(BMI$get(paste0("V", 2)), BMI$get(paste0("V", 1)), g) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Which packages are we using: `summarize` ? *Hmisc* ?

Comment: My bad...changing the representative code

Comment: summarize from Hmisc package

Comment: Do you mean summary()?

Comment: no...summarize function in Hmisc package

Comment: @MrC FYI,  it is customary to include the `library(Hmisc)` statement in your code so that it is unambiguous for others trying to help.

Comment: sorry...missed it in hurry. Any help on the issue?